# How to run a shell script with export command in crontab

Tags: shell, shell-script, cron, environment-variables

I have a shell script that **exports** values of variables when executed. The same values will be used in another script.
How to run this script(**test.sh**) in cron.

```
#!/bin/sh
export I="10"
echo $I
```

I will be using root access for cron.
I tried this command :

```
*/5 * * * * /home/ubuntu/backup/.test.sh
```

I checked with environment variables, nothing is updated.

Comment: Exporting variables makes them visible to their *children* not to the *parent* shell. How is *another script* called? From within test.sh or from the parent shell?

Comment: test.sh is one script that exports the value. test2.sh is another script the uses the value of I stored as environment variable

Comment: It depends on how does test2.sh get called? If its called by test.sh, then that should be ok. Otherwise it will probably not take over these variables.

Answer (score 3):

Environment variables can only be passed down between a process and a direct process child.  It cannot change or export environment variables to different process trees.  Further, the exported variable is only available to process again that are direct descendents of the current process, NOT at the same level as the export is done.

Answer (score 2):

In fact variables aren't shared across scripts in cron. Even if you define an environment variable like it says in the  [manpage](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man5/crontab.5.php) if you have a script that changes that variable it won't really change for the second script.
However, you can use a temporary file (you can even create it in memory if you don't want to rewrite a file on disk) to use between scripts.

For examle:

```
10 * * * * /path/to/script1.sh
20 * * * * /path/to/script2.sh
```

Contents of script1.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "VAR1='VALUE1'" > /dev/shm/cronsharedfile
```

Contents of script2.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /dev/shm/cronsharedfile
do_something_with $VAR1
```

In this case the second script will have the correct value assigned by script1.sh.
I used a file kept in shared memory (/dev/shm/cronsharedfile) but you can create a file on disk (/path/to/whateverfile) .

Answer (score 0):

If there are 2 scripts in picture, then the variable exported in the first one would be visible to the next one. So, if you have a cron entry like

```
*/5 * * * * ( test1.sh; test2.sh ) > log.txt
```

And *test1.sh* as

```
#!/bin/sh
export I="10"
echo $
```

Then `$I` would be visible in *test2.sh*.

Comment: What? No. Whatever `test1.sh` does in its environment has no impact on `test2.sh`. If you wanted that, you'd need to write `. test1.sh; . test2.sh`.

Comment: hmm. May be I had tried the way you showed. I guess sourcing is then really different that running a program from a PATH directory ?

Comment: Yes, sure, sourcing is different. `. test1.sh` tells the current shell to parse and execute the commands in `test1.sh`. `test1.sh` runs the external program `test1.sh` which may or may not be a shell script.